# htaccess to redirect all trafic from http to https but to also redirect to index.php which is hidden once on https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I am looking for a .htaccess file which can do the following, I've managed to get each function to work individually but not together.

Requirement no 1:
All HTTP traffic is redirected to HTTPS

Requirement no 2:
All HTTPS URLs are directed to index.php?url_params=

I either end up with an endless loop on the request_uri or I end up with server error:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} = http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?url_path=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So if someone was to type in "http://www.example.com/page1" it would redirect to "https://www.example.com/page1" and then "https://www.example.com/page1" is sent to index.php with page1 sent as a url param

Thanks

D

Comment: What is your Apache version and are you behind some proxy or cloudfare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Result: This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Change `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` and retest